# Effect of non-divisible loop sizes at runtime on openMP SIMD

Tags: c, openmp, simd

After reading several different articles and not finding an answer I am going to introduce the problem and then ask the question.

I have a section of code that can be reduced down to a series of loops like look like the following.

```
#pragma omp parallel for simd
for(int i = 0; i < a*b*c; i++)
{
    array1[i] += array2[i] * array3[i];
}
```

Now most examples of SIMD use that I have encountered have a, b and c fixed at compile time, allowing for the optimisation to take place. However, my code requires that the values of a b and c are determined at run time.

Lets say that for the case of the computer I am using the register can fit 4 values, and that the value of a*b*c is 127. My understanding of compilation time for this is that the compiler will vectorise everything that is wholly divisible by 4, then serialise the rest (please correct this if I am wrong). However this is when the compiler has full knowledge of the problem. If I were to now allow a run time choice of a, b and c and came to the value of 127, how would vectorisation proceed? Naively I would assume that the code behind the scenes is intelligent enough to understand this might happen have have both a serial and vector code and calls the most suitable. However, as this is an assumption, I would appreciate someone more knowledgeable on the subject to enlighten me further, as I don't want accidental overflows, or non-processing of data, due to a misunderstanding.

On the off chance this matters, I am using OpenMP 4.0 with a C gcc compiler, although I am hoping this will not change your answer as I will always attempt to use the latest OpenMP version and unfortunately may need to routinely change compiler.

Comment: You can check what your compiler generates, by compiling with `-S`. Often compilers already unroll and SIMD-optimize the loop, even without openmp: https://godbolt.org/z/SCTxzf (play around with compilation options and the `#pragma`).

Comment: OpenMP doesn't require that the values of (in this example) `a,b,c` be fixed at compile time, only that they be available when the loop is encountered, so that the run-time can distribute the work across the available threads.  I'm not sure this has much to do with the rest of your question.

Comment: If you want easily to see the code which is generated, so that you can understand it, the Compiler Explorer https://godbolt.org/ is your friend. https://godbolt.org/z/N4Mvmk shows something like your code (I've omitted the parallel since that seems irrelevant your question). You can, of course, play with other compilers and compare the outputs there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, a compiler will unroll beyond the simd length.  For optimum results, particularly with gcc, you would specify this unroll factor, e.g. --param max-unroll-times=2 (if you don't expect much longer loops).  with a simd length of 4, the loop would consume 8 iterations at a time, leaving a remainder.  gcc would build a remainder loop, somewhat like Duff's device, which might have 15 iterations, and would calculate where to jump in at run time.  Intel compiler handles a vectorized remainder loop in a different way.  Supposing you have 2 simd widths available, the remainder loop would use the shorter width without unrolling, so that the serial part is as short as possible.  When compiling for the general case of unaligned data, there is a remainder loop at both ends, with the one at the beginning limited to the length required for alignment of the stored values.  With the combination omp parallel simd, the situation gets more complicated; normally, the loop chunks must vary in size, and one might argue that the interior chunks might be set up for alignment, with the end chunks smaller (not normally done).

Comment: GCC's cleanup loops look basically nothing like Duff's Device.  DD is an unrolled loop with multiple entry points (which is only any good on an ISA with post-increment addressing).  GCC's cleanup code is the opposite: it usually fully unrolls a loop (without optimizing away the branching) into a chain of cmp/jcc with work in between.  This can get very bloated for 32 or 64-byte vectors with small element sizes.

Comment: gcc8 and later doesn't align pointers with prologue loops.  Arguably it *should* in some cases, but not with super-bloated fully-unrolled scalar loops.  If gcc knew how to do a possibly-overlapping first/last vector iteration that has basically no overhead in the aligned case, that would probably be even better.